# How to recognize if a PictureBox has entered another PictureBox or a Label?C#

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, c#-4.0, windows-forms-designer

I am controlling picturebox1 with arrow keys and when I enter picturebox2(or label2) I need to know if picturebox1 entered the picturebox2 and bring the picturebox1 straight out of picturebox2. (I know about mouseEnter just so you know.)

Here is my code for moving the picturebox1(if that helps):

```
int x = picturebox1.Location.X;
int y = covjek.Location.Y;

if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right) x += 3;
else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left) x -= 3;
else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up) y -= 3;
else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Down) y += 3;
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean you just want to keep picturebox1 on top of picturebox2? Or what do you mean by "bring it straight out of"?

Comment: Compare the Bounds properties of each PictureBox.  Rectangles have an IntersectionWith function you can use.

Comment: if picturebox1 enters picturebox2 area then bring back picturebox1 out of the picturebox2 area(if that makes seanse)